# how to pass existing activities to for-each activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

my overall tasks exists of 2 activities.

1. Copy from REST to SQL staging
2. MAP from SQL staging table to original Table

at pipeline level i have 2 variables.

payload to pass jsonPayload and then i want to run the above mentioned 2 activities in a loop against different urls. for that i have a second pipeline level parameter called 'relativeURLs' which is and array of urls.

in a foreach loop i want to call my activity 1 and 2 but when i click foreach it looks like i have to define my activities 1,2 from scratch. cant i simply refer the existing ones?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try having those 2 activities in other pipeline which accepts parameters and call this new child pipeline from "Execute Pipeline" avtivity inside for each loop

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. hold CTRL and select the two activities. Right click and copy. Then double click on the for loop activity to open it. Paste the activities there.